# Angular 7 'undefined' Variable

Tags: angular, angular7

Is it possible to listen to the subscriber function from outside?

```
x:string;
listenertwitchService(){
     console.log(this.x);
}

this.twitchService.getUserID(this.Tw_Username).subscribe(data => {
     this.x="123";
});
```

Comment: you will get undefined in your log because x is not initialized.

Comment: How it is not initialized

Comment: you just specified the type of x not the initialize value so when the log it it would be undefined and after log your request will done and x will be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Its is a normal behavior:

1) Your x is not defined

> x:string;

```
//should be
x = '';
```

2) Observables work asynchronously , meaning if you want to use the x return by `this.twitchService.getUserID(this.Tw_Username)` you need to use rxjs pipe and operators, because trying to access a global variable whose value is set asynchronously is not a good idea since its hard to know the the value of x will be set i.e when your Observable will fire. **However for template binding its quite useful to bind your global variable given you set an initial value see (1)**

```
    this.twitchService.getUserID(this.Tw_Username)
   .pipe(tap(data)=>{ //or any other operator ie map/switchMap etc...
      //do the thing you want to do to the data
    })
   .subscribe()
```

for more info: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/

Answer (score 0):

If you `console.log(this.x)` after `subscribe` it still is undefined, because `subscribe` call `asynchronous`, it will not wait return data from `getUserID` and run next line of code

```
 this.twitchService.getUserID(this.Tw_Username)

            .subscribe(data => {
        this.x="123";
 });

//still undefined
console.log(this.x)
```